# Aligning three divs side by side in a single row

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to align three divs side by side without any flexbox and grid.

This is the style that I'm looking for: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZKZU.png)

This is what I'm currently getting: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Llq3.png)

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.box-1 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box-2 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box-3 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
</div>
```

Note: Just asking about alignment, not the border, background etc

**Edit**: The parent container has width 600px. It cannot be changed. And the children have 180px width and 100px height, and margin of 10px.

Comment: Something that might help - https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Hey increase the width of the container as follow:

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.box-1 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box-2 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box-3 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
</div>
```

or use `display : flex` in your container both will help....

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it using `display: flex;` layout on `.container` class.
The default direction of `flex` layout is `row` (`flex-direction: row`).

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}
.box-1 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box-2 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box-3 {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "*I'm looking to align three divs side by side without any flexbox and grid.*"

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use Flexbox, You can simply try increasing the width such that all 3 divs are aligned in  a single line
like Aahad said...